# How to get value of selected dropdown item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the value `id` of the selected item in my dropdown. Currently I am trying to console log the value but I keep getting undefined. My data is not empty and contains information. What am I doing wrong? I am using a dropdown component from `rsuite`

```
testValue = (selectedValue) => {
    console.log(selectedValue);
}


            <div className='pipeline-nav' style={{ width: 250 }}>
                    <Sidenav
                        defaultOpenKeys={['1']}
                        activeKey='1'
                        appearance='inverse'
                        className='company-nav'
                    >
                        <Sidenav.Body>
                            <Nav className='nav-bar'>
                                <Dropdown
                                    className='nav-dropdown'
                                    eventKey='1'
                                    title='Company Filter'
                                >
                                    {this.state.companies.map((item) => (
                                        <Dropdown.Item
                                            eventKey={`1-(${item.id})`}
                                            key={item.id}
                                            value={item.id}
                                            onClick={e => this.testValue(e.target.value)}
                                        >
                                            {item.name} (
                                            {item.vacancies_count})
                                        </Dropdown.Item>
                                    ))}
                                </Dropdown>
                            </Nav>
                        </Sidenav.Body>
                    </Sidenav>
                </div>
```

Comment: The answer entirely depends on the imlementation of Dropdown and Dropdown.Item. Are these from a library or something? Did you make these yourself?

Comment: Why don't you just do this on Dropdown.Item: `onClick={e => this.testValue(item.id)}`

Answer (score 1):

adding id={item.id} to the dropdown and                                                 onClick={e => this.testValue (e.target.id)} worked!

Comment: that's a very roundabout way of getting the value -- you take it from the item, set it on the element, and then get it from the element -- when you could have just skipped those steps and got it from the item itself, which would be the normal react way of doing things. `onClick={e => this.testValue(item.id)}`

Answer (score 0):

Does your Dropdown component has property like onChange, use that instead of having onClick at item's level.

Comment: onChange doesn't fire the console.log. My concern is that the value becomes undefined, but I am able to get something when I do innerHTML, although I am in need of its numerical value.

Comment: My Dropdown component does have a property of eventKey but when I log the value of eventKey, it also gives property undefined